# More formal way of saying "fighting until the end"

Tags: synonyms, australian-english

I'm currently working on a history essay and said "Saladin choose to declare a truce with the Crusaders in 1192 instead of fighting until the end."

It gets the point across but I think it's a little basic. Looking for a way to rephrase '*fight until the end*' to something more fitting of a historical essay assignment.

Comment: It don't hurt to be basic. It's classic. Anyway, why the truce, really? To avoid losing more soldiers? To avoid total defeat? To save face? All good reasons and better explanations than *until the end*, which doesn't explain much. Readers don't want formality, they want information.

Comment: This is a little off. Both sides fight to the end. That's what the end is; it's the end of the fighting. Did he want to fight to finally end? Or to not go on forever?

Answer (score 1):

"Fight to the last man standing" or just "fight to the last man".
I found these phrases used in a news article on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fight-last-man-johnson-resigns-fred-zheng):

> Boris Johnson has finally fought himself to the last man standing.

and in the name of a book:

> [Dunkirk- Fight to the Last Man](https://www.historynet.com/military-history-book-review-dunkirk-fight-last-man/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the technical term is a *last stand*, which has an entire page devoted to the [tactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_stand).

Answer (score -1):

[Die in the last ditch.](http://www.english-for-students.com/die-in-the-last-ditch.html)

> die desperately defending something
>
> die fighting to the last extremity
>
> This expression comes from a remark attributed to King William III (1650-1702). Asked whether he did not see that his country was lost, he is said to have responded : There is one way never to see it lost, and that is to die in the last ditch. Last-ditch is often used as an adjective meaning desperately resisting to the end.

Comment: Not sure this is any more formal. Talk of ditches is certainly no more *elevated* or *grand*.